# IntelliJ IDEA tends to format SQL files into one column

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I am tried to format SQL file with IntelliJ IDEA and got something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO SpectralImages
(scanDataID,
 imageToolsetID,
 imageTypeID,
 imageFilename,
 imageDSPath,
 fileID)
  (SELECT
     ScanData.scanDataID,
     1,
     Files.imageTypeID,
     Files.fileName,
     Files.fileDSPath,
     Files.fileID
   FROM ((
       Files
       LEFT JOIN
       Samples_Files
         ON (
         Samples_Files.fileID
         =
         Files.fileID)) LEFT JOIN
     Scans
       ON (
       Scans.sampleID
       =
       Samples_Files.sampleID)) JOIN
     ScanData
       ON (
       ScanData.scanID
       =
       Scans.scanID)
   WHERE
     Files.imageTypeID
     IS
     NOT
     NULL
     AND
     Files.fileID
     NOT
     IN
     (SELECT fileID
      FROM
        SpectralImages)
   GROUP BY
     scanDataID,
     Files.fileID);
```

Apparently it tries to put each term into separate line. Is this normal?

Are there any other formatting options with more reasonable line wrapping?

Comment: Did you resolve the problem using the code formatting options for SQL?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA offers a lot of formatting options for SQL, you can disable newlines where needed:

[image: sql formatting]